# How can I get fileID or parentID in python Google-drive APIs ??

Tags: python-2.7, google-drive-api

such as from this example below
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get

how/where can i retrieve fileId to use this code? the method require fileId as its parameter ,but I don't know how /where i get it

Comment: I answered this particular question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13558653/how-can-i-create-a-new-folder-with-google-drive-api-in-python

Answer (score 1):

You would use the list() function to find the list of files in the domain, probably specifying the q attribute to search/query for certain files:
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list

the returned files resource has an id parameter you can use to get the individual file and perform updates, sharing, etc.

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource