# how to get the file id of a file in google drive using php

Tags: php, google-drive-api

hi there i've been `googling` for hours about how to get the `id` of a file uploaded to `google drive` using `php`.. so far the uploaded files are each uniquely named and i've found this answer but it's for `python`.. but i want one for `php` [How can I get fileID or parentID in python Google-drive APIs ??](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13568315/how-can-i-get-fileid-or-parentid-in-python-google-drive-apis) this other one is for php though but i have no idea how to make it work.. https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the question.

Go to the page you referenced and you will find

```
  $createdFile = $service->files->insert($file, array(
      'data' => $data,
      'mimeType' => $mimeType,
    ));

    // Uncomment the following line to print the File ID
    // print 'File ID: %s' % $createdFile->getId();
```

Comment: but i get the following error `Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\upload\Google-Drive-PHP-API-Simple-App-Example-master\Google-Drive-PHP-API-Simple-App-Example-master\index.php on line 47` and the question was the files are uniquely named i just want to get the id of the file at any time not only during upload.. hope i made myself clear.. :P

Comment: Either maintain your own mapping of name to id, or use the query facility of files.list to search by name. Note that you will probably also need to exclude trashed files.